# Can I exit the airport on a layover in China?

Tags: airports, china, hotels, sleeping

I am a Canadian citizen with a Canadian passport, I am considering a flight with an overnight layover in Chengdu. I am just looking for a place to crash.
Will I be able to stay in a hotel? How will I know which hotel I can stay in? Will I need a short stay visa?

I am new to traveling. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Canadian citizens do not require a visa if:

- Visiting Chengdu for up to 72 hours.
- In a transit between 2 pre-purchased international flights.
- Traveling via Chengdu Shuangliu International Airport.
- Passport must be valid for at least beyond 6 months from the day you expect to leave China.

Read more: [source](https://travel.gc.ca/destinations/china)

As far as hotels are concerned, of course, you can stay. Just book a hotel at your convenience from places like [Trivago](https://www.trivago.com) etc